# Server Error in '/' Application after system reboot

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, iis, windows-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2013.

I've installed some Windows Update on my Win Server 2008 R2 and then rebooted my server.

After that my Sharepoint website returns: "Server Error in '/' Application."
The same error trying to browse Central Adm from my server.

I've also tried to do IISrest and recycled all applications pool.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if the SQL Server Service is up and running..

Comment: Useful suggestion! Thank you. SQL didn't start and log reports: "The log scan number (9130:424:1) passed to log scan in database 'master' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup."

Comment: So its not related to SharePoint, AFAIK.. you need to fix the curropted master database and the SQL Service should be running again..